# Adding new attribute to QgsFeature object

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have tried reading the docs located [here](https://qgis.github.io/pyqgis/master/core/QgsFeature.html#) but there is no mention of any method that allows you to add new attributes to the feature only modify existing ones.

Something along the lines of:

```py
QgsFeature.addAttribute(name='Score')
```

A snippet from my code where I attempted to find a workaround is shown below:

```py
        #create score field by copying fields from origin
        #and append the new score field
        fields = QgsFields(source.fields())
        fields.append(QgsField('Score', QVariant.Int))

        for feature in features:

            #set score for each feature
            score = 12

            #set score attribute
            feature.setFields(fields, initAttributes=False)
            feature['Score'] = score

            #add feature to the output
            sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
```

However, when I run the plugin I am making, there is no errors but the output has no attribute named Score.

Note: the score variable is not going to be equal to 12 for each feature I just changed it to be like that for simplicity. It will actually be calculated for each feature based on the features in the source layer.

Comment: You need to register the new attribute on the layer level, not the feature.

Answer (score 2):

```py
fields = lyr.fields()

# create a field instance
name = 'Score'
new_field = QgsField(name, QVariant.Int)

# open an edit session, it closes automatically after the block is executed
with edit(lyr):
    # add new field to the layer if it does not already exist
    if name not in fields.names():  
        lyr.addAttribute(new_field)
        lyr.updateFields()

    # get the index of the new field
    idx = fields.indexFromName(name)

    for f in lyr.getFeatures():
        lyr.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), idx, 12)  # (feature id, field index, value)
```