# Nested for: I execute changeAttributeValue in the outer loop, print it and is still NULL... but inner loop works kind of fine?

Tags: pyqgis, null, for-loop, values

A bit hard to explain, untill now my script is:

I have a for, where:

if  an "Analized" attribute is NULL, I will change it to "Parent",store a "Join Value" attribute in a variable, then run an inner for in the same layer where: if  "Analized" attribute is NULL and has the same "Join Value" as the first one its labeld as "Child" in the "Analized" attribute.

The idea of the Parent and Child thing is that i dont run the first "for" for attributes already labeld as "child".. but it always reads "Null" in the outter for. I know it works fine in the inner, as the elements in my db file are categorized correctly (i run it in a small test dbf). But

The original table is quite big and it usually takes the Open Field Calculator a few hours to compute simmilar calculations, so this step is important.

Script:

```
Ejes_duplicados.startEditing()
AnalizadoIdx = prov.fieldNameIndex("Analizado")
print (AnalizadoIdx)


for eje in Ejes_duplicados.getFeatures():
    print("-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----")
    Analizado=eje['Analizado']
    Eje_id=eje['E_ID']
    HP=eje['HP']
    if Analizado==NULL:
        print("-----------------ANALIZADO: ",Analizado)
        ID = eje.id()
        print (ID)
        NewValue='Parent'
        
        Ejes_duplicados.changeAttributeValue(ID, AnalizadoIdx, NewValue)
        Analizado=eje['Analizado']
        print (Analizado)        
        for eje2 in Ejes_duplicados.getFeatures():
            print("-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----")
            Eje_id2=eje2['E_ID']
            Analizado2=eje2['Analizado']
            if Analizado2==NULL and Eje_id2==Eje_id:
                print("XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO: ",Analizado2)
                ID2 = eje2.id()
                print (ID2)
                NewValue2='Child'        
                Ejes_duplicados.changeAttributeValue(ID, AnalizadoIdx, NewValue2)
                Analizado2=eje2['Analizado']
                print (Analizado2)
                HP=HP+eje2['HP']
                pass
            else:
                print('ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE  ',Analizado2,Eje_id2 )
                pass
```

Console:

```
5
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
0
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
1
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
2
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
3
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
4
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
1
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
2
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
3
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
4
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
2
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
3
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
4
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
3
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXANALIZADO:  NULL
4
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
4
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
5
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
6
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   NULL 3
-----x-----x-----x-----x-----OUTER LOOP-----x-----x-----x-----x-----
-----------------ANALIZADO:  NULL
7
NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Child 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 1
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent NULL
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 2
-----x-----x----INNER LOOP-----x------x-----
ANALIZADO O DISTINTO EJE   Parent 3
```

Comment: You probably need to add `Ejes_duplicados.commitChanges()` after your loop to close the edit session and save the changes. Otherwise you can use a `with edit(...)` block as per  [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421863/128665)

Comment: Could you please add tags to your question to indicate which software you are using? (I assume it's QGIS). Shouldn't `NULL` be `None` in Python?

Comment: Hi @Matt , I'll  try "with edit" option. Reading about it now!

Comment: @Berend Its pyqgis. Thanks! forgot about the tag.